# I want to create dynamic buttons and divs and later on be able to retrive or add an img tag within the div section using Asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net

This is what i have so far:

```
string theImagepath = "../image.jpg";

string themessage = "hello";

for (int i=0; i<12; i++)
{
    RecentPosts.InnerHtml = RecentPosts.InnerHtml + "<div id='d1' runat='server'><div>"
}
```

My problem is that I can't access the dynamically created `div`.

Comment: Why do you need to access them? just create them the way you want before dumping them to the page

Comment: You can not access a literal control the same way you access a normal control. However, javascript will have no problem accessing those for you. Just make sure you give each control its unique `ID`. So in your loop, make the iterator `i` part of the id

Answer (score 0):

First I need to clarify this:

> You can't add a server control through client side javascript. Server controls are rendered on the serverside and sent to the client. <sup>*1</sup>

Second is around this web a good methods to workaround this for example 
[Dynamically add controls javascript Asp.net C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13989741/dynamically-add-controls-javascript-asp-net-c-sharp) in which the answer make some literals and read his values with .net event.

you can try this also:[add asp.net control using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863237/add-asp-net-control-using-javascript) they are using updatepanel to catch the request and add the buttons or whatever .net control you need. Check the links and make some test.

<sup>*1</sup> = taken from one answer of the second link and some experience doing this.